Create unique list and sum up values per unique row (without defining the filter criteria multiple times in the LET function)



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1
Data List





Filter_01
Filter_02



2
date
brand
type
prod.
val.

Br_B
t1



3
2022-05-10
Br_A
t1
P1
15

Br_C
t2



4
2023-01-15
Br_A
t1
P1
18


t3



5
2022-08-12
Br_B
t2
P2
30






6
2022-09-15
Br_B
t3
P3
50

Result




7
2023-06-15
Br_B
t1
P3
20

prod.
val.



8
2023-06-18
Br_B
t4
P1
80

P2
80



9
2024-05-17
Br_B
t4
P4
25

P3
122



10
2023-08-19
Br_C
t3
P5
85

P1
80



11
2022-09-30
Br_C
t5
P3
70

P4
25



12
2024-04-25
Br_C
t5
P3
32

P5
85



13
2025-08-29
Br_D
t3
P1
45






14
2022-03-25
Br_E
t1
P2
60






15
2022-03-26
Br_E
t3
P2
85






16
2024-05-20
Br_E
t5
P3
90






17
2024-06-03
Br_E
t2
P4
15






18
2024-07-30
Br_E
t1
P4
26







In Cell G8 I have implemented this formula:
=LET(
a,COUNTIF(G2:G4,B2:B18)+AND(G2:G4=""),
b,COUNTIF(H2:H4,C2:C18)+AND(H2:H4=""),
c,FILTER(A2:E18,a*b,""),
d,CHOOSECOLS(c,4,5),
d)

This formula does not yet give the results displayed in Range G8:H11 because it does not list the prod. uniquely and sum up the val. per unique prod..

Although the solution from this question comes close to what I need it does not fully solve the issue in this case because I am looking for a formula in which I only have to define the filters once and not multiple times. Additionally, compared to the other question the filters are a bit more complex since they refer to a range with multiple criteria. 
Summarized, I am looking for something like this:
=LET(
a,COUNTIF(G2:G4,B2:B18)+AND(G2:G4=""),
b,COUNTIF(H2:H4,C2:C18)+AND(H2:H4=""),
c,FILTER(A2:E18,a*b,""),
d,CHOOSECOLS(c,4,5),
e,unique_list_with_summed_up_values_based_on_a_and_b;
e)

How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?
Note: I am using Office365 (Version 2410) and I do not have the GROUPBY function yet.

You are repeating similar questions everytime with little or minimum changes. also the output you have shown doesn't yield the desired result with the criterias given. are you sure what you have posted?

Please explain in detail how you obtain the output you are showing from the data and filters you are using. They do not appear to match.

Give a try to the following formula-
=LET(x,FILTER(D3:E18,COUNTIFS(G2:G4,B3:B18)*COUNTIFS(H2:H5,C3:C18)),
y,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(x,1)),
z,MAP(y,LAMBDA(t,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(x,CHOOSECOLS(x,1)=t),2)))),
HSTACK(y,z))



Thanks for your answer. It works in my Excel file. However, in the screenshot that you posted in your answer it does not show the output in my Excel file. Maybe you need to update it because on my Excel the output from your formula is correct. Additionally, I modified your answer with the option that if no filter criteria is entered in the ranges it still works.

@Michi Please do not edit another users answer to change what it does. If you want a different answer then add it as a new answer, referencing the original answer to explain the change and why something else is needed. Edits to code in answers must be carefully considered. Fixing typos and clear errors can be OK but changing the answer to do something else is probably wrong.

@Harun24hr I nearly rolled back the edit, but decided to do nothing in case you approve of it.

@AdrianHHH this post needs to be closed because OP has neither explained nor has given any response to those asking for a clarification, if you notice minutely you can see those conditions which are set doesn't return the expected output as is desired. Even the answer proposed doesn't meet the requirements even with the edit made by OP. It clearly doesn't explains the logic how prod P3 is returning 122 against 70 and how does prod P4 shows up in the output. OP has confused others while accepting an answer which may or may not be the correct solution.
